# Adding Tags Functionality To Existing Component

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, component, fof, tags

I'm looking to get tags working inside of an extension. I saw [**this**](http://docs.joomla.org/Tag_form_field_type) and have gotten the field to appear in the edit view, but of course it doesn't save anywhere.

Looking at com_content article tag handling, it goes through a thorough mapping exchange before the relationship is complete. So I see it builds the tag-to-content relationship inside of `#__contentitem_tag_map`. Would I need to make a new table like this in my component specifically for tags or is this just the way com_contant handles it and I can get tags to save into just a column like any other field type?

Would I need to do this for the extension, or is there something I'm not utilizing that would make the process considerably more simple?

Perhaps a "concise adding tags to your extension 101" maybe useful.

I haven't seen anything specifically through any of the docs mentioning tags in this context, but in case it's relevant, I developed this extension using FOF/RAD.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should get you going - http://docs.joomla.org/J3.3%3aHow_To_Use_Content_Tags_in_Joomla!

Admittedly it was a little difficult to get going at first, and if you're supporting 2.5 on the same code base there are other challenges (I can link you to commits on a project when I'm not on mobile).

Comment: Yeah, I've looked at that, but I guess the added look at code and possibly step process as well will help tremendously.

Comment: This should help some.  Initial commit - https://github.com/BabDev/Podcast-Manager/commit/48c23e6528fa263ec83c481971ef8bf64eac9bb2  Adding data to the mapping tables - https://github.com/BabDev/Podcast-Manager/commit/b4f4d73c081ee12d18e11d4fc3c43608e478cca6 & https://github.com/BabDev/Podcast-Manager/commit/c37fd52916ef94d947500c8c17eb1da02c57bd92  Final work - https://github.com/BabDev/Podcast-Manager/commit/f1caea9f6d62aa8ee724bae005d4f1dbd2e48e0b