# How to debug an empty Bootstrap error generated by non-empty Tags field in a custom component?

Tags: custom-component, tags, error-reporting

Flowing on from [my previous question about writing my first component](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/23391/12352) (now called **com_picture**) which is nearly an exact clone of the **com_contact** directory, I have hit a snag with trying to save a new "picture" with a tag.

When I save a picture without a value in the tags field, everything is sweet.

[image]

---

However, when I try to save a picture **with** a value in the tags field (I mean the cute little blue bubble with the tag value is generated in the tags field in the lower right of the window), I receive a vague/useless bootstrap error:

> Error Save failed with the following error:

[image]

If I make changes to the Name, Alias, Category, Language, etc. -- all of those changes are preserved after I click save.  It is ONLY the tags field that is failing.

I have set my Global Configuration - Server - Error Reporting to: "Development" and read through all of the queries, but there are no INSERT queries (which I expected to see when adding a new tag) and the 2 UPDATE queries are not relating to the tag table. Basically, there are no clues in the 37 queries logged.

If anyone, for some uncanny reasons, actually knows what I've done wrong please share.  **Otherwise, I'm merely asking how I can generate some informative error messages/clues as to what I've done wrong.**

As a bit more background, I've cloned the com_contact directory then done a case-sensitive replacement on all occurrences of `contact`, `Contact`, and `CONTACT` with `picture`, `Picture`, and `PICTURE` -- this was the simplest way forward for this prototype because it seamlessly handled singular/plural versions of the keyword for filenames, classes, functions, variables, etc.  I also copied and adjusted all rows in all tables (I believe) which refer to com_contact so that com_picture is represented and all ids are pointing to the correct rows.

And in case it helps to dismiss some suspicions, I am able to generate a full error message when I try to save a duplicate picture in the same category:

> Error Save failed with the following error: Another Picture from this category has the same alias (remember it may be a trashed item).

So I am thinking that this eliminates the possibility that I've overlooked a language .ini file. (maybe / maybe not)

I am running Joomla 3.8.12  I am happy to implement any wild guesses so that I can move forward.

I have already updated the `#__content_types` table by copying the Contact row and making `contact` -> `picture` replacements.

```
(15, 'Picture Category', 'com_picture.category', '{"special":{"dbtable":"#__categories","key":"id","type":"Category","prefix":"JTable","config":"array()"},"common":{"dbtable":"#__ucm_content","key":"ucm_id","type":"Corecontent","prefix":"JTable","config":"array()"}}', '', '{"common":{"core_content_item_id":"id","core_title":"title","core_state":"published","core_alias":"alias","core_created_time":"created_time","core_modified_time":"modified_time","core_body":"description", "core_hits":"hits","core_publish_up":"null","core_publish_down":"null","core_access":"access", "core_params":"params", "core_featured":"null", "core_metadata":"metadata", "core_language":"language", "core_images":"null", "core_urls":"null", "core_version":"version", "core_ordering":"null", "core_metakey":"metakey", "core_metadesc":"metadesc", "core_catid":"parent_id", "core_xreference":"null", "asset_id":"asset_id"}, "special":{"parent_id":"parent_id","lft":"lft","rgt":"rgt","level":"level","path":"path","extension":"extension","note":"note"}}', 'PictureHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute', '{"formFile":"administrator\\/components\\/com_categories\\/models\\/forms\\/category.xml", "hideFields":["asset_id","checked_out","checked_out_time","version","lft","rgt","level","path","extension"], "ignoreChanges":["modified_user_id", "modified_time", "checked_out", "checked_out_time", "version", "hits", "path"],"convertToInt":["publish_up", "publish_down"], "displayLookup":[{"sourceColumn":"created_user_id","targetTable":"#__users","targetColumn":"id","displayColumn":"name"},{"sourceColumn":"access","targetTable":"#__viewlevels","targetColumn":"id","displayColumn":"title"},{"sourceColumn":"modified_user_id","targetTable":"#__users","targetColumn":"id","displayColumn":"name"},{"sourceColumn":"parent_id","targetTable":"#__categories","targetColumn":"id","displayColumn":"title"}]}');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To support tags in your component, you must add your content type to `#__content_types` table.

Documentation: [Using Tags in an Extension](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Using_Tags_in_an_Extension)

You have copied the row where:

```
`type_title` = 'Contact Category' AND `type_alias` = 'com_contact.category'
```

To create a new row for:

```
`type_title` = 'Picture Category' AND `type_alias` = 'com_picture.category'
```

but you haven't copied the row where:

```
`type_title` = 'Contact' AND `type_alias` = 'com_contact.contact'
```

to be a new row for:

```
`type_title` = 'Picture' AND `type_alias` = 'com_picture.picture'
```

Comment: I have updated my question to include the row that I already inserted into the table.

Comment: I didn't want to bloat my question any farther with a bunch of sql rows that I manufactured, but I might need to add these details for absolute clarity.

Comment: You added a row for `com_picture.category` but not for `com_picture.picture`.

Comment: I did read that documentation page, but I mustn't have looked carefully enough about what I was doing.  Thanks for the extra pair of eyes.  The tags are now saving.  Any ideas as to why I can't get version notes to save on any of my components? Or shall I post a new question?

Comment: ...nevermind about the version note.  Everything is working as intended, I misunderstood the functionality.

Comment: Please forgive my question extension... I am now trying to package up my component and I need to write the above two rows into `sql/updates/mysql/1.0.0.sql.sql` and `sql/updates/install.mysql.utf8.sql`.  However, the `type_title` column in `#__content_types` is not UNIQUE by default, so I can't do a `INSERT IGNORE`.  Do I need to something more complicated like a post_flight script to check and conditionally insert the two rows?  Inspiration from Prof. Babker: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/708/12352

Comment: If this is the initial release of your component (e.g. 1.0.0), you don't need an update file. Add the queries to install file only. Remember to remove ID columns/values from the query - these must be auto incremented. Going forward (1.0.1 and beyond) any SQL changes will need to be made in both install and update files.

Comment: Right.  I've `null`ed the id column values. I am solely concerned with subsequent installs where I have additional .sql files in the `updates/mysql` folder.  If I duplicate the two-row INSERT query, I'll be generating redundant rows.

Comment: Update files are incremental. They must include only changes introduced with their versions. For example, if you add a new content type in 1.0.1, you need to create a 1.0.1 update file containing the query and also update the install/uninstall files. If you don't make any database changes in 1.0.2, you don't even need a 1.0.2 update file. But if you do, the update file must contain only changes introduced in 1.0.2. Changes from 1.0.1 will be applied automatically from 1.0.1 file.