# How to integrate my custom Administrator component with core Joomla database tables during install?

Tags: extensions, mysql, custom-component, installation, component-configuration

**Background:** I am starting to package up three associated custom Joomla extensions that I've developed.  (This is directly associated with [my previous JSE question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/23899/12352), if you want more context.)  The package contains a component (`com_o3_picture`) that started as a clone of `com_contact` from the core, then was adjusted to suit client needs.  Additionally, there is a `editors-xtd` plugin to generate placeholders into Articles and a `content` plugin to replace the placeholders with dynamic content.

Because I am using much of the same functionality of `com_contact`, my `install.mysql.utf8.sql` file creates a `#__o3_picture_details` table.  This is successfully done already.

A couple of months ago, when I test-installed my component by itself, I realized that I didn't have the `Pictures>Pictures` and `Pictures>Categories` submenus that I needed in the Administrator Menu's `Components>Pictures` (to mirror the options that Contacts provides).  So I manually inserted some rows into `#__menu` to solve the problem.  This was something that I "eye-balled" because I needed to reference generated ids to properly assign the parent-child relationships.

**Questions:**

1. How do I automate the Menu option process?  Can this be cleverly done in the `install.mysql.utf8.sql`? or do I use a preflight call? or postflight? or an entirely different/better way?
2. I know [I need to insert to `#__content_types`](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/23442/12352).   Are there any essential rows in other tables that should be inserted/updated?  I mean, `#__assets` is a table that might not *need* to be spoken to, but I'd rather do everything in my install rather than running a sync from PWT's ACL asset fixer.  Another example is `#__associations` -- I don't think I need to do anything to that one do I?

How can I be sure that I've created everything that is expected? Trial and Error?  ...I'd rather not.  Anyone have some experience/expertise to share?

Comment: Thank you for your concern regarding fringe cases with future extensions, but for this project, integrating K2 is not planned.  I believe that Sharky's answer is what I am looking for,  but I haven't finished packing things up and therefore haven't tested my package install.  Once I have run the install, I'll be able to accept or ask for further support/clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Administrator menu items can be added to manifest file's `<administration>` section:

   ```
   <menu img="class:example">COM_EXAMPLE</menu>
   <submenu>
       <menu
           link="option=com_example"
           img="class:example-items"
           alt="Example/Items">COM_EXAMPLE_ITEMS</menu>
       <menu
           link="option=com_categories&amp;extension=com_example"
           view="categories"
           img="class:example-cat"
           alt="Example/Categories">COM_EXAMPLE_CATEGORIES</menu>
   </submenu>
   ```

   https://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files#Menu_links_and_submenus
2. Unless you want to insert some sample items on installation, no. Component record will be added to `#__assets` table automatically.

Comment: Would you mind tailoring your snippet to closer align with the context in my question? And I didn't come across this menu-submenu advice while researching; can you provide a reference to the Joomla Documentation about this technique so that I (and researchers) can read more?

Comment: Added link to documentation. What changes do you propose to the snippet?